# push data into array with label (typescript)

Tags: html, angular, angular2-forms

appcomponent.html

```
<input type="text"  #name><input type="text"  #fname>
<input type="button" value="add" (click)="mymethod(name.value,fname.value)">
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">{{hero.name}} -- {{hero.fname}}</li>
</ul>
```

appcomponent.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyserviceService } from './myservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [MyserviceService],
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  heroes=[];    
  constructor(private _myservice:MyserviceService){}
  ngOnInit(){
      this.heroes=this._myservice.heroarr();
  }
  mymethod(name:string,fname:string){

    this.heroes.push(name:'hi',fname:'hello');

  }
}
```

i've tried this code to push single data into array and it works well.when i want to send data with label it indicates error.if anybody know pls let me know.

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: ERROR in /root/project/disdata/src/app/app.component.ts (17,23): ',' expected.

Comment: this.heroes.push({name:'hi',fname:'hello'}); isnt it the correct way to push an object??

Comment: You can't directly push values indeed

Comment: thanks for the help bros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
let newHero  = {
  name:'hi',
  fname:'hello'
}

this.heroes.push(newHero);
```